# Restarting entire A-Frame component from if / else

Tags: javascript, aframe

Edit 2: Turns out you can specify the duration of the tick function so it acts as a timed refresh (quite useful). The number is in milliseconds and this 'tick' replaces the 'init' at the beginning of the component registration.

```
tick: function () {
    this.tick = AFRAME.utils.throttleTick(this.tick, 8000, this);
```

Edit: Thanks to Piotr the setAttribute("world"," ") call does indeed work. In my case I used `.setAttribute('truefalse', '')` though (truefalse being the name of my registered component). Unfortunately it only works for a single loop though. I'm not sure what could be done to make it re-update every time the condition is met.

ORIGINAL: There is a Javascript component in my A-Frame that has a lot of code inside which I want to refresh near the end when an 'if / else' condition is met. I already have everything running, but cant figure out how to use the `else {` declaration to restart the initial 
`AFRAME.registerComponent('world', { 
init: function () {`

Should I be using a `update: function () {`, or something like that, or do I have to use some kind of 'for loop' code? I'm sure this is a very common question so I'm sorry if it has been asked a lot already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("world", {
  init: function() {
    /*here you do what you want to be done once, 
    for example add event listeners */
  },
  update: function() {
    /* this function will run every time components will receive new data */ 
  }, 
  tick: function() {
    /* this function will run on every frame.
       Be frugal with creating objects here -
       too much objects will result in poor performance */

  },
  myCustomFunction: function() {
  }
});
```

If `myCustomFunction` is what you want to do on every `tick`, use:

```
tick: function() {
  this.myCustomFunction();
}
```

If `myCustomFunction` is what you want to do on every time component receives new data, use:

```
update: function() {
  this.myCustomFunction();
}
```

**Update after reading comments:**

```
tick: function() {
  if(.....) {
    ...
    this.update();
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm having some trouble understanding what the update: function is doing though. I just want to reapply everything in the component up to that point once I hit the if / else statement. I've tried placing the update: function() {  code after the 'else' section but its not doing anything.

Comment: I don't need an update on every tick, but I'm unsure if I'll be needing a custom function. All I want to do is reactivate the init: function when an 'if' event triggers.

Comment: @DarioSilva the update() is called each time you make a setAttribute("world"," ") call

Comment: I don't know what your `if` statement does, but if you want to check for a condition all the time, and then trigger some function, ex. `update()`, you can place `if` statement in `tick`. I'm updating the answer so you can see it. Update might as well be replaced with your custom function of course.

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski Could you please show me in this code what I have to do for this code to update more than once after clicking on the text? At the moment when you click the text it refreshes once (setAttribute) but then will not refresh again. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lumpy-pedestrian?path=index.html:61:0

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski I got it, you can use a tick function and specify the mlliseconds. Just thought I'd let you know. Cheers.